# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: and other error

Tags: java

I have created a file java named "cancelladir" that is in a directory name "cancelladir", when I write, in my ubuntu shell,  "javac cancelladir.java" It create a cancelladir.class  but when I try to execute the file java with the command "java cancelladir " there are some error like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cancelladir (wrong name: cancelladir/cancelladir)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I have already set the classpath at `export CLASSPATH=.:/home/lisa/graphhopper/graphhopperAndrea/web/src/main/webapp/cancelladir` and try to recompile  but nothing change.
What is the problem?? what I have to do?

Comment: did you debug the code to find what line of code throw the error?

Comment: Its not able to find your class in the classpath. Open a new command window and try to set the classpath like export CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH} :.

Comment: what is the code and the procedure that I have to use to do do what you have write? sorry but I am a begginer in java

Comment: I mean open a new Ubuntu shell and type    export CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:.    and try ti invoke your program "java cancelladir".   ${CLASSPATH} command will retain the existing classpath and . would set the current directory in the classpath. I asked to try in new shell because your previous trial could have removed  the default classpath.

Comment: If I use the command echo $CLASSPATH the result is: :./home/lisa/graphhopper/graphhopperAndrea/web/src/main/webapp/cancelladir

Answer (score 1):

After you compile your code, you end up with .class files for each class in your program. These binary files are the bytecode that Java interprets to execute your program. The NoClassDefFoundError indicates that the classloader, which is responsible for dynamically loading classes, cannot find the .class file for the class that you're trying to use. It probably indicates that you haven't set the classpath option when executing your code. This link explains how to set the classpath when you execute

Answer (score 1):

1) Open a new shell and add a new simple program like this. 
2) Compile the java code using javac Hello.java 
3) Run the code using java Hello 
It should work, if you still have issue let know.

[image]

Comment: Did you try this simple Hello.java program ? Can you paste the stack trace ?

Comment: Sorry now It work (only the simple code of Hello.java)

Comment: Ok I got your actual problem. I think you are using package for your code at the first line. eg. package com.example; If you use package you need to compile using javac -d . cancelladir.java and execute using javac com.example.cancelladir. Try like this your actual code should work now.

Comment: The second code is java com.example.cancelladir not javac, but you are my SAVIOR!!! =) THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: Yes your are right...it was a typo.. Good luck on Java